# Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subseteq X \mid \text{ $A$ countable or $A^c$ countable} \}$. Show that $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}).$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be an uncountable set and $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subseteq X \mid \text{ $A$ countable or $A^c$ countable} \}$. Show that $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}).$

Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Now we can express $A = \bigcup_{x \in A} \{x \}$. Either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable. If $A$ is countable then the set $\bigcup_{x \in A} \{x \}$ is a countable union of singletons from $A \subseteq X$ and thus belongs in $ \sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \})$. If $A^c$ is countable then $A^c = \left(\bigcup_{x \in A} \{x \}\right)^c = \bigcap_{x\in A} \{x\}^c =\bigcup_{x \in A^c} \{x\}$ and $A^c$ is countable so again this would be the union of countable singletons and therefore in $\sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \})$? So $\mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \})$.

How can I approach the other direction? The set $\sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \})$ is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}$ by definition, but this set $\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}$ is uncountable so how can I show that $\sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \}) \subset \mathcal{A}$?

If I pick $A \in \sigma(\{\{x\} \mid x \in X \})$, then is $A = \{\{x_1\}, \{x_2\}, \dots \}$ for $\{x_i\} \in X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to show the other inclusion. Just remember that $\mathcal B = \sigma(\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\})$ is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\}$. The conclusion follows as, clearly, $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \subset \mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal B$.

Comment: This is what I know, but I don't see how it implies the result?

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: I guess my issue is with the fact that $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \subset \mathcal{A}$. I'm not sure how this set belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. The sets $\{x\}$ are clearly countable as they're singletons, but the set containing all these singletons e.g $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\}$ is not neccessarily countable since $X$ is not countable?

Comment: Be careful: I wrote $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \subset \mathcal A$, not $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \in \mathcal A$. $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \subset \mathcal A$ just means that every $\{x\}$ are in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Let me try to explain myself. Since $X$ is uncountable and $\sigma(\mathcal{B}) \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ it can also be uncountable. Now any $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{B})$ is a set of singletons (possibly uncountable). How can $B \in \mathcal{A}$ since $B$ could be uncountable? It seems that I don't understand the difference between $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{B})$ and $B \subset \sigma(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Let $A = {a_i~|~i \in I}$ and $B = \{b_j~|~j \in J\}$. We have $A \subset B$ if, for all $i \in I$, there is $j \in J$ such that $a_i = b_j$. However, we have $A \in B$ if there is $j \in J$ such that $A = b_j$.
Indeed, we do not have $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \in \mathcal A$ but we have $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\} \subset \mathcal A$ as all $\{x\}$ are in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: I guess this is a bad day for me since I'm not able to understand this. $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{B})$ is a single set consisting of singleton sets. and $B \subset \sigma(\mathcal{B})$ is a set of sets consisting of singelton sets. But either one can be uncountable.

Comment: What is $B$ ? You mean $\mathcal B$ ?

Comment: $B$ is just some element of the sigma-algebra generated by $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$. As far as I know if I can pick an arbitary element $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{B})$ and show that this element is actually also in $\mathcal{A}$, then I've shown the inclusion $\sigma(\mathcal{B}) \subset \mathcal{A}$. However I'm not able to convince my self that $B$ would be countable.

Comment: Indeed, showing that $B$ in countable may be difficult, that's why I exposed an other way. Do you agree that $\sigma(\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\})$ is the smallest sigma algebra generates by the set $\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\}$ ?

Comment: I do. That's the definition.

Comment: Therefore, if we are able to find another sigma algebra $\mathcal A$ includes in $\sigma(\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\})$ that contains all of the generators $\{x\}$, the only way is that $\mathcal A = \sigma(\{\{x\}~|~x \in X\})$.

Comment: I've managed to convince myself of the following. Since each $\{x\}$ is countable $\{\{x\} \mid x \in X\} \subseteq \{A \subseteq X \mid \text{ $A$ countable or $A^c$ countable} \}$. And since we have that $A \subset B \implies \sigma(A) \subset \sigma(B)$ we get that $\sigma(\mathcal{B}) \subset \{A \subseteq X \mid \text{ $A$ countable or $A^c$ countable} \} = \mathcal{F}$. I thank you for your patience!

Comment: This is exactly that! You are welcome.